# How to fetch an attribute value from xml using powershell and replace with string content

Tags: powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc>
   <myTask id="MyBatchExport" name="MyBatchExport" scriptFormat="javascript">
      <task><![CDATA[var requestItemsParm= execution.getVariable("requestItems");
      var requestItemsParm= JSON.parse(requestItemsParm);
      var batchExport = {};]]></task>
   </myTask>
   <myTask id="MyBatchImport" name="MyBatchImport" scriptFormat="javascript">
      <task><![CDATA[var requestItemsParm= execution.getVariable("requestItems");
      var requestItemsParm= JSON.parse(requestItemsParm);
      var batchImport = {};]]></task>
   </myTask>
</abc>
```

Based on the Mytask tag id value, have to replace the task data with other string content using powershell

```
$xmldata = [xml](Get-Content test1.xml);
$StrContent = "my own content to replace in between CDATA"
$taskdata= $xmldata.abc.myTask.task
```

with above assignment, i can get all task data as array. But i want to task tag value if id is equal to "MyBatchImport" or "MyBatchExport" or some "xyz"

Can someone help me here

Comment: The sample document is missing a namespace declaration, please post valid xml

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen updated xml

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has a nice feature called [Member Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/#member-enumeration) which might come at hand when reading properties:

```
$xmldata.abc.myTask.task |Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Xml.XmlElement

Name                 MemberType            Definition
----                 ----------            ----------
ToString             CodeMethod            static string XmlNode(psobject instance)
...
WriteTo              Method                void WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter w)
Item                 ParameterizedProperty System.Xml.XmlElement Item(string name) {get;}, System.Xml.XmlElement Item(string localname, string ns) {get;}
#cdata-section       Property              string #cdata-section {get;set;}
```

But it might get confusing when you want to write data because you will need to be specific in the node branch you want to write (as it would be incorrect to write to all branches in once).

In this specific case the branche is at the `$xmldata.abc.myTask`:

```
                     ┌─ [0].task.'#cdata-section'
$xmldata.abc.myTask ─┤
                     └─ [1].task.'#cdata-section'
```

So you will need to define whether you want to change the first or the second `mytask`. In case you want to replace the first `mytask` (in the *zero based* array):

```
$xmldata.abc.myTask[0].task.'#cdata-section' = $StrContent
$xmldata.Save([Console]::Out)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<abc>
  <myTask id="MyBatchExport" name="MyBatchExport" scriptFormat="javascript">
    <task><![CDATA[my own content to replace in between CDATA]]></task>
  </myTask>
  <myTask id="MyBatchImport" name="MyBatchImport" scriptFormat="javascript">
    <task><![CDATA[var requestItemsParm= execution.getVariable("requestItems");
      var requestItemsParm= JSON.parse(requestItemsParm);
      var batchImport = {};]]></task>
  </myTask>
</abc>
```

Comment: I want to fetch <task> content based on <mytask id="matchedString"> value @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron

Answer (score 1):

To resolve a set of nodes based on some condition relating to their *parent* nodes, `XPath` is usually the right tool for the job.

For example, to get the CDATA section under only those `<task>` nodes whose parents are `<myTask>` with a `name` attribute value of `MyBatchExport`, you could use the following expression:

```
$targetNodes = $xmldata.SelectNodes('//myTask[@name = "MyBatchExport"]/task/text()')
```

Then simply loop over each resolved node and update the contents:

```
$targetTaskNodes |ForEach-Object { $_.InnerText = $StrContent }
```

Comment: tried below, but $targetNodes getting null
$targetNodes = $xmldata.SelectNodes('//myTask[@id= "MyBatchExport"]/task/text()')
@Mathias R. Jessen